# Limiting string text within div

Tags: jquery, string, text, limit

Can someone tell me if their is a way to limit text within div classes.

example

```
<div class="mon">December</div>
<div class="mon">November</div>
<div class="mon">October</div>

$('.mon').hide().text();

var month = $('.mon').text().substr(0,3);

$('.mon').append(month).show();
alert(month);
```

trying to output

Dec
Nov
Oct

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('div.mon').text(function() {
    return $(this).text().substring(0, 3);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uwomi5)

[`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), like a lot of other "setter" functions of jQuery (`html`, `attr`, etc.), accepts a function it will call to get the value to set for each element.

Answer (score 3):

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) can take a function, like this:

```
$('.mon').text(function(i, t) { return t.substr(0, 3); });
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/LS8AM/).